# how to use nested EL in this case?

Tags: java, jstl, el

I have empId as 600 and custId as 400 under session object. I want to apply jstl function on it. Basically
i want to apply my project specific Taglib function on "600-400"

i tried like below

```
"${myProject:Taglib(${sessionScope.empId}-${sessionScope.custId})}"
```

but getting below error

```
javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [${myProject:TaglibFunction(${sessionScope.empId]
```

I know i can do it in two separate lines i.e

```
 <c:set var="intermediateVar" value="${sessionScope.empId}-${sessionScope.custId}" scope="page" />

 var finalValue= "${myProject:TaglibFunction(intermediateVar)}";
```

But is there a way i can do it in single line ?

Comment: No.  You cannot nest el expressions in the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

When you are already within an expression you should not have to  ${} again.  Try:

**Edit:**  What types are the variables empId and custId?  What type is the argument to TagLibFunction?  From your question it looks like that method is looking for a string concatenation of empId (dash) custId.  Without more details as to the back end function/variables I am only guessing here

Instead of:

```
"${myProject:TaglibFunction(sessionScope.empId + '-' + sessionScope.custId)}"
```

Try:

```
"${myProject:TaglibFunction(sessionScope.empId-sessionScope.custId)}"
```

Either way, your problem stems from the nested expressions. ***${${}}***

Comment: it does not work. Gives error i.e java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-"

Comment: Edited.  Hope it helps. Just don't use an inner ${}. You should be fine referencing your other vars from the same expression.